# DataGridCell IsReadOnly ControlTemplate trigger to change background color -

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

The goal is to assign proper color to the wrapping border (that makes the `ControlTemplate` targeting `DataGridCell`) when the columns has `IsReadOnly` set to false.

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border
            Margin="8"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            CornerRadius="4">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDarkForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The color is assigned correctly
[image]

However when some row is selected and then cursor leaves the mentioned row, the assigned coloring disappears and I am left with the default one. It happens only when the row is still selected.

[image]

The considered columns which are the only ones which are not `ReadOnly` are defined in the following way

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Binding="{Binding PreviousMonthResult, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource textCenterEditing}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource textCenter}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border
                Padding="8"
                Background="{StaticResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}"
                CornerRadius="8">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDarkForeground}" Text="{Binding DataContext.DateHeaders[PreviousMonth], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn
    Binding="{Binding CurrentMonthResult, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource textCenterEditing}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource textCenter}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border
                Padding="8"
                Background="{StaticResource SecondaryHueMidBrush}"
                CornerRadius="8">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDarkForeground}" Text="{Binding DataContext.DateHeaders[CurrentMonth], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Where `textCenterEditing` and `textCenter`

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="textCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>

<Style
    x:Key="textCenterEditing"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}"
    TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

However I guess these "small" styles should not interfere with achieving the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using some material design styling there which might be a complication, not sure.

The problem is due to the selected brush, applied at row level.

If you're not bothered about highlighting selected row background the you can set it transparent.

Roughly:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

You might want to use the foreground brush to denote selection.

There might possibly be a more elegant material design orientated solution.